# How do you calculate the time-time component of a tangent vector in spacetime?

Tags: special-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, vectors

The norm of a tangent vector of a spacetime manifold is the sum of the square of its components:$$\lVert \boldsymbol {V_t}\rVert^2=\left(\frac{\partial t}{\partial\tau}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial\tau}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial\tau}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial\tau}\right)^2$$
All the spatial terms are already in the same units as the tangent vector. That is, those terms have units of $m\space s^{-1}$. However, the time-time term is unitless. How can we compare a unitless value to $m\space s^{-1}$?

Some people have suggested that you just change the basis vector for the time component to $ct$, but that just moves the exact same problem to the basis vector. What's the justification for saying $ct$ is equal to a unit length of space? Why not use $kt$ or $(c+at)$ for the basis vector?

Can we, instead, interpret the time-time term to be a fraction of the total vector? That is, instead of just jamming an ad hoc constant into the time-time term or the time basis vector, is it more fair to say:
$$\lVert \boldsymbol {V_t}\rVert^2=\lVert \boldsymbol {V_t}\rVert^2\left(\frac{\partial t}{\partial\tau}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial\tau}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial\tau}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial\tau}\right)^2$$
And then we draw whatever conclusions we can from the fact that $V_t=c$?

**EDIT:** Let's assume the signature is (-,+,+,+) to make it simple.

Comment: That's essentially how they're defined in the first place - you define basis vectors of length (for example) 1 metre in each spatial dimension and 1 second in the time dimension, then you measure everything relative to those, and you note that the scaling factor of 1 metre = $c$ seconds gives you a dimensionless system. You might also want to read up on the [geometrized unit system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometrized_unit_system).

Comment: "Jamming" a $c^2$ in the first term is not a "kludge."  It is Einstein's foundational insight linking space-like to time-like dimensions.

Comment: You know, it's usually helpful to be less aggressive when asking a question. Just because you don't understand why the equation is the way it is doesn't mean there isn't a good reason.

Comment: The factor of $c$ is 100% related to physics, so if you're talking about special/general relativity, you can't ignore it. Mathematically all you need is to understand tangent spaces and tangent vectors (look up any differential geometry text), and also Lorentzian metrics. Physics is not math; you have to encode the physics precisely into a mathematical framework. So, you can't magically come up with $c$ based on geometry. Also, where are your minus signs in the equations?

Comment: @Quarky:  Holding a PhD in physics, studying special and general relativity, astrophysics, and cosmology at MIT and UMd, teaching the subject at the college and university level, I know well that $c$ is hardly "religion" but the essential factor that unifies scales in space- and time-like dimensions in the 4-geometry of space-time.  Of course ($c + at$) cannot preserve fundamental invariances, as it gives a "special" status by changing signs for sufficiently negative $t$, and other geometric reasons.  I see my expertise isn't appreciated here, so I'll just bow out and let Quarkly work on this.

Comment: @Quarkly when you see $t$ in the context of relativity i.e in physics, people have already chosen to work in a system of units where $c=1$ is dimensionless, so time and space have same units. If you like, then use $x^0=ct,x^1=x,x^2=y,x^3=z$, so that the coordinates $x^a$ all have same units. As for why $x^0=ct$ and not $x^0=\tilde{c}t$ for some other $\tilde{c}$, then that's what I'm referring to as being part of physics. Anyway, if you open up any math book, all you'll see is "consider a coordinate system $(U,x)$ on a manifold $M$..."

Answer (score -2):

Just with length, the metric tensor is used to normalize the different components of the tangent vector:$$g_{\mu\nu}=\begin{bmatrix}c^2&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
So the equation in the original post is more accurately described by:
$$\lVert \boldsymbol {V_t}\rVert^2=g_{00}\left(\frac{\partial t}{\partial\tau}\right)^2+g_{11}\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial\tau}\right)^2+g_{22}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial\tau}\right)^2+g_{33}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial\tau}\right)^2$$The last part of the puzzle, provided by this Wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor) is understanding that the length of the tangent vector, $\frac{\partial t}{\partial\tau}$, is given by:$$\lVert \boldsymbol {V_{00}}\rVert^2=g(0,0)=c^2$$